# Site Health : An active PHP session was detected

Tags: php, theme-development, session, site-health-widget

I'm new in WordPress development and I just created my first theme.

In my wp-admin, the `"Site Health"` tells me that a PHP session has been detected (critical error), here is the message :

> A PHP session was created by a session_start() function call. This
> interferes with REST API and loopback requests. The session should be
> closed by session_write_close() before making any HTTP requests.

I need PHP's `$_SESSION` for a theme script, and I added this to my functions.php file for sessions to be properly initialized:

```
<?php

if (!session_id()) { 
    session_start(); 
}
```

If I delete these lines, the message disappears, but my PHP sessions don’t work anymore.

If I keep these lines, everything seems to be working properly but this message is worrying...

Does anyone have an idea to solve this problem while keeping the ability to use the `$_SESSION`?

My WP version is `5.5.3` and the PHP version is `7.4.8`.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't think so, no. I think this is WordPress telling you it wants you to use something other than $_SESSION. Either use something else or just ignore the warning (if you're happy it won't actually break anything for you). I'd guess there'd be a way to suppress the warning with a filter if you look.

Comment: Or maybe I'm misreading it: maybe it's OK for you to use $_SESSION as long as you don't make any outbound web service requests?

Comment: Thanks for your help Rup! It’s annoying for me to use something other than `$_SESSION`. Maybe WordPress doesn’t like sessions? Making that message disappear with a filter won’t solve anything. What worries me is that this message is marked as a critical error. I thought there was another way to initialize and use sessions with WordPress, and maybe I was taking it wrong. About outbound web service requests, I don’t know if this has an impact.

Comment: In my case, it was caused by plugin "Send PDF for Contact Form 7". Deactivated and it's solved. created support ticket with the plugin developer.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same issue.

I replaced the code

```
session_start();
```

with

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
  session_start(['read_and_close' => true]);
}
```

and it worked for me.

Comment: That would fix two plugins both trying to start sessions, but wouldn't fix the Site Health warning in the question because that's because WordPress doesn't want you to use session_start at all.

Comment: @rup I was getting critical warning of session in wordpress "site health". So I applied the above code and it solved my issue.

Comment: Thank's Shiv,
If I use your solution, the error message disappears but I can no longer use $_SESSION in my PHP scripts, they are no longer initialized :-(

Comment: @Loraga
`session_start ( array $options = [] ) : bool`
session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.
a `read_and_close` option may also be provided. If set to true, this will result in the session being closed immediately after being read, thereby avoiding unnecessary locking if the session data won't be changed.
Please see [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

I think in your case you have to start session and have to put values in it again.

Comment: Thanks for the link @shiv.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused by the plugin "Contact Form by BestWebSoft".

If you find yourself in the same situation you have to disable the plugin one by one and refresh the page `/wp-admin/site-health.php` to check if the error is still there.

As explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64377032/getting-an-active-php-session-was-detected-critical-warning-in-wordpress this is due to a plugin badly developed.

Comment: Thank's Francesco,
I had already disabled all extensions before asking my question here, unfortunately, this did not solve the problem. I don't use any of the extensions mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that WP e-Store causes:

1. An active PHP session was detected
2. the REST API encountered an error

WP SpamShield causes:

1. An active PHP session was detected

I'll look at the code and see if I can find a way to fix it in these plugins. Without e-Store, the site is basically dead in the water!

If anyone had found and fixed either of these plugins, I'd love to know what worked.

jshumphrey@gmail.com

Comment: Welcome to WPSE. As a rule, we don't offer support to third-party plugins. However, it seems to me that you could reword your question to ask about programmatically correcting the fault. However, for the bugs with the plugins themselves, the best I can do is suggest you enquire wherever support is offered for these plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this same issue. After many attempts at hooking to call `session_start()` elsewhere within the Wordpress loading process, a colleague suggested I try replacing my code in functions.php with the following:

```
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

This seemed to fix both issues I was having, clear the error in Wordpress, and allow my front end users to log into the system I had created.

Comment: Thank you @Lee. This did not suffice in my case though so devised my own solution based on yours. See answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Lee's answer and @shiv's link to the [PHP documentation for session_start](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#example-4810), I came up with this that solved my issues. Could possibly work in the case of the OP as well.

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start([
        'cookie_lifetime' => 86400,
        'read_and_close' => true,
    ]);
}
```

One can note this was with the issue persisting also with all plug-ins disabled.